# Where did the notion of 'calling' a function come from?

Tags: terminology, language-agnostic, history

I've always wondered why one *calls* a function as opposed to, for example, *executing* it.

A Google search for `function call etymology` and similar terms turns up nothing useful, Wikipedia doesn't mention it, online dictionaries have either [no entry at all](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Function+call&searchmode=phrase) or [no etymology section](http://www.finedictionary.com/function%20call.html).

Where did the notion of 'calling' a function come from?

Comment: It probably comes from the different semantics for handling the arguments - call by value, call by reference, call by name, etc. I also imagine that the term originated with "procedure call" or "subroutine call" and was only applied to functions later. In mathematics you *apply* functions to their arguments, and what we call functions are almost always procedures/subroutines (because mathematical functions don't have side effects).

Comment: @Doval: Yes, but why use the very "call" in "procedure call" instead of a different verb?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner No clue, but I figured they'd have better luck trying to find the origins of "subroutine call" or "procedure call" than "function call", which doesn't make sense historically. I realize the comment doesn't answer the question, but that's precisely why I made it a comment and not an answer.

Comment: In lambda-calculus you *apply* a function (and the *lambda* operator is making *abstractions*). Some languages speak of *invoking*, not calling, a function.

Comment: @Doval: good idea, I only know it as '*pass* arguments by value/reference etc.', though.

Comment: In some dialects of assembly language (such as x86 assembly) the opcodes are named `call` and `ret` or some variant thereof. It is possible that programming languages inherited the terminology from the underlying hardware, although that would still leave the question of why the hardware designers chose those names for the operations.

Comment: Most languages I use only use `call` for procedures, subroutines or methods, but use `apply` for functions (e.g. Haskell, Scala, ML).

Comment: A synonym for 'invoke' is 'call'.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't disagree with you about λ-calculus, but note that the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) for that term uses "call" in several places to explain what it means to apply a function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word *call* goes back at least to Fortran, the first widely used programming language. In Fortran, `CALL` is [a keyword that passes control to a subroutine](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0129.htm). It's not clear why [John Backus](http://www.computerhistory.org/fellowawards/hall/bios/John,Backus/) chose that word to invoke subroutines -- you may need to read one or more biographies of Backus to discover that -- but it seems likely that the use in Fortran is the reason that we use the word *call* today with respect to functions, methods, etc.

Note that the use of *call* with respect to functions and other subroutines also fits well with several English-language [definitions of *call*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call?show=0&t=1408629192):

- to make a brief visit
- to demand something
- to rouse from sleep
- to invite

Comment: OP wants to know why CALL in the first place.

Comment: @user61852: exactly. @Caleb, thanks for your input, but it's not quite what I had in mind. Do you know why it was called `CALL` and not something else?

Comment: David Wheeler's 1952 ACM paper _The use of sub-routines in programmes_ describes the concept, and I'd bet the use of the term "call" evolved between then and the appearance of `CALL` and `RETURN` in FORTRAN II in 1958, if it wasn't used in the paper itself.  (I'm too cheap to pay the ACM $15 to find out.)

Comment: @Timo Although I can't point to the origin of the term, my goal with this answer was to get you closer to that point. Knowing that `CALL` shows up in this context in Fortran (created in 1954) should significantly narrow the search for the origin. Blrfl's comment above looks like a good bound on the early side, so together we've narrowed the time period in which the term seems to have come into use to a few years.

Comment: @Caleb:  `CALL` wasn't a part of the first version of FORTRAN.  See page 1 of the [IBM Fortran II Reference Manual](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102653989.05.01.acc.pdf).

Comment: @Blrfl Great link -- thanks for that. **Also:** Just guessing, but the term `CALL` w.r.t. a subroutine might be related to the English meaning of *call [on]* as making a brief visit, as in *I called on the Smiths today.* We don't often use the word that way today (unless you watch a lot of period TV/movies), but it wasn't uncommon back in the 1940's and 1950's.

Comment: @Blrfl I skimmed the paper, it does not use the term `call` or any other term, it mostly just talks about `use of` subroutines.

Comment: @LarsViklund I think that's the point -- had the term `call` been in use at that time the paper was written, it surely would have been used. Therefore, the paper provides some evidence that the term probably came into use between then and Fortran II.

Comment: @Blrfl I looked into this as well. While I can find references that document what a "call" is, I can find nothing that explains the rationale for _why_ the action is named "call." It makes sense, but I cannot find the genesis of the term.

Comment: I asked a similar question on SO and in the referenced paper the following is said: In this type of routine it is arranged that a sequence of operations is performed each time the subroutine is *called* into action.

So despite the term not formally being used, this gives a hint of the informal thinking behind it.

Comment: Looking at how the word `call` is used in the [FORTRAN II Reference Manual](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102653989.05.01.acc.pdf) provides some hints. They use "call for", "call in", "call into". E.g.: "call for a sub-program" and "the subroutine [blah] could be called into the main program by the statement". They only use `call` by itself as a verb once: "the arguments in the CALL statement used to call this subprogram."

Answer (score 2):

1947:

> In January 1947 John Mauchly presented general notes at 'A Symposium of Large Scale Digital Calculating Machinery' under the joint sponsorship of Harvard University and the Bureau of Ordnance, United States Navy.

> ...a coding instruction for placing the subroutines in the memory at places known to the machine, and in such a way that they may easily be **called into use**."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_programming)#History

Comment: This seems like more evidence that use of `call` in early computing languages like FORTRAN comes directly from English usage at the time. The word can be used with a number of prepositions that each change its meaning a bit: call up, call back, call on, call out, call to, call for, etc., but it can also be used alone as a way to request service, e.g. *call the butler*. I'm not sure it's worth updating my 10yo answer, but the ultimate answer to OP's question about where the word came from seems to be "from common English usage."